# Why might wsusutil export to a .xml.gz file produce a 0 byte output?

Tags: wsus

We're doing monthly updates to a disconnected network with Server 2012 installed on all servers.

Last month (February), the export created a 60 megabyte .xml.gz. Today, it creates a 0 byte file timestamped at the start of the export and the log's timestamp hits at the end of the process.

Any ideas where to look next? Google just returns results for the .cab 0 byte issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. Yo have to install a patch for WSUS.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wsus/archive/2013/04/09/problem-solved-the-wsus-export-bug.aspx

Comment: I believe this fixes the `.cab 0 byte issue` that the OP emphasized is not his current problem, no?

Comment: Does that patch fix the xml coming out as 0 or just let you use the xml format?